# How to pipe STDOUT from a spawned child into a log file and print it to the console at the same time?

Tags: node.js, stream

I've searched far and wide but I can't find a straight answer for this.

- I want to spawn a child process.
- I want to pipe the child's STDOUT stream to a log file.
- I **also** want to see the same STDOUT lines printed 'live' in the terminal in which I'm running the parent process (ideally with each line prefixed with `[child]` so I can distinguish these lines as being from the child process).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You should be quite safe to simply use `readable.pipe` twice:

```
const child = require("child_process").spawn('/usr/bin/command', ["arg"]);

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/var/log/command/access.log'));
```

This works just fine in some methods in my framework, `scramjet` - especially the [tee](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet-core/blob/master/lib/data-stream.js#L123) method works this way.

Just keep in mind that the output speed will be limited by the slower of the two writables.

Comment: Quite safe? Is it actually safe (and officially supported use of the API) or not? I've seen several comments suggesting streams don't work like this, that once a chunk has been read, that chunk is gone.

Comment: For sure the streams do work like that - see this [double pipe example on Github](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet/blob/develop/samples/so-examples/double-pipe.js).

In the on("data") case this actually is the case.

Comment: I think you mean `child.stdout.pipe()`.

Comment: Right. Fixing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do both action with `subprocess.stdout` like this:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

let log = fs.createWriteStream('file.log')
let subProcess = spawn('subProcess')

subProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  process.stdout.write(`[child] ${data}`)  // log to console
  log.write(data)  // log to file
})
```

See *Michał Czapracki*'s answer for a solution using `pipe()`.

Comment: My only concern is the Node docs say you *should never* use a mixture of the `.pipe()` and EventEmitter approaches when consuming streams (see [Choose One](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_choose_one) in the stream API docs). I'm not clear on the reason for this advice though.

Comment: There is a problem... or a sort of one - the stream piped to fs may not receive all the data. Another one - using console.log there is not actually so cool as that one adds a new-line on each entry - two pipes, as in my proposed answer is the solution to both issues.

And the actual code you wrote has a minor bug stopping it from working correctly - the second to last line does pipe(log) - which returns log, then the last line sets a listener on log - which doesn't emit data events - because it's the writable one.

Comment: @MichałCzapracki Interesting remark. But I'm not convinced. I'd glad to see an example where it would not work. But your solution seems good too.

Comment: Try a slow stream to `pipe` to and use `on('data')`. It will not miss the a lot of the file, because the `pipe` method will control the flow - but when you attach "data" listener to the stream, you actually put it into flowing mode. This ***may*** output some data from the buffer before the pipe is ready and then it would get omitted. If you cared to ask this question separately - we could check it out...

Comment: @MichałCzapracki After testing it again, I can confirm that you're right. I'll update my answer. Thanks for pointing that.